# Generating unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a column 'Keys' in a table. With data Like this

```
Key    Name
1      aaa
2      sads
null   asd
null   asd
```

Now I need to replace null values with 3 and 4. How can I do that.

Comment: Is that the whole structure of the table? No identity fields? And you want duplicate `Name`s with different `Key`s?

Comment: from the provided example it is not completely specified how you'd like to do it. What is the order in which you'd like to assign 3,4...?

Comment: yes I want different key values for same names.

Comment: However, currently there is no way to tell the duplicate rows apart - is that also right?

Comment: Are all existing key values sequential, and lower than the new values to be assigned, i.e. Do we want to assign MAX(Key)+1 - MAX(Key)+N to the N rows which currently have NULLs?

Comment: @Nadeem, Oded, Unreason and Damien_The_Unbeliever have all entered comments asking for clarification on your requirements and you have replied with what is essentially the same answer each time. **WE ALL UNDERSTAND THAT YOU WANT UNIQUE VALUES IN THE KEY FIELD.** It would help the other Stack Overflow users to help you if you could answer some of these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which version of SQL Server you're working with, you'd use TOP or SET ROWCOUNT to limit an UPDATE to a single row. Something like this will work:

```
select top 1 * from sysobjects
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP 1 Keys SET Key = (SELECT MAX(Key) from Keys)+1 WHERE Key is null
END
```

But isn't ideal. I can't think of another way of addressing the duplicate rows - unless this is a one-off task, in which case temporarily adding an IDENTITY column would work.

Comment: @Nadeem - not sure which parts you want explained. If you've tried it and it didn't work, what type of error was produced? For other aspects, it would be preferable if you added more info to your question. What version of SQL are you using? Is this a one-off task, or will you be running it regularly? If regularly, is there a reason why the NULLs cannot be prevented in the first place.

Comment: +1 for "add identity column", the correct answer and the right way to do it

Comment: +1 for updating one row at a time. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put the data (temporarily) into a separate table you can use ROW_COUNT():

```
declare @Keys table ([Key] int not null, [Name] varchar(50) null);

insert into @Keys ([Key], [Name])
select [Key], [Name]
from   [Keys]
where  [Key] is not null
union all
select [Key] = row_number() over (order by [Name]) + 
               (select max([Key]) from [Keys]),
       [Name]
from   [Keys]
where  [Key] is null;

truncate table [Keys];
insert into [Keys] select * from @Keys;
```